# Display contents of external text file on clicking google-chart bar

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-visualization

So far I am able to display a bar-chart using google charts. At the minute the values are hard coded but I will take these from a mysql table later. My question is - is it possible to have individual alerts displayed depending on what bar has been clicked in the chart? E.g. Jim's fails. I want to be able to click each bar individually and have an alert displayed containing the contents of one of multiple external .txt files. So far I can display the same alert when I click on any of the bars.

```
<!--Load the AJAX API-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

  // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
  google.load('visualization', '1.0', {'packages':['corechart']});

  // Set a callback to run when the Google Visualization API is loaded.
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  // Callback that creates and populates a data table,
  // instantiates the pie chart, passes in the data and
  // draws it.
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Student');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Passes');
data.addColumn('number', 'Fails');
    data.addRows([
      ['Jim', 199, 4],
      ['John', 154, 15],
      ['Peter', 246, 32]
    ]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'Nightly Build Results',
                   'width':800,
                   'height':400};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);

function selectHandler(e)
{
    alert('Information');
}

  }
</script>
```

Update:

```
function selectHandler()
{
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
      var message = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < selection.length; i++)
  {
        var item = selection[i];
        if (item.row != null && item.column != null)
        {
     if(item.row == 0 && item.column == 1)
    {
        message = 'Jims passes.';
    }
         else if (item.row == 0 && item.column == 2)
    {
        message += 'Jims fails.';
    }
        } 
  else if (item.row != null)
  {
          var str = data.getFormattedValue(item.row, 0);
          message += '{row:' + item.row + ', column:none}; value (col 0) = ' + str + '\n';
  }
  else if (item.column != null)
  {
          var str = data.getFormattedValue(0, item.column);
          message += '{row:none, column:' + item.column + '}; value (row 0) = ' + str + '\n';
      }
    }

    if (message == '') 
    {
      message = 'something not yet added';
    }

    alert('You selected ' + message);

  }
```

So I have the individual bars displaying what I want them to (on click) well, at least 2 bars so far for testing. I am wondering how I will populate this alert with text from a file on my webserver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `selectHandler` you can get the row and column that has been selected like so:

```
function selectHandler() {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
}
```

The `selection` variable is now an object with both a `row` and a `column` property. Click on the bar for Jim's number of fails would return the following:

```
column: 0
row: 2
```

Similarly, clicking on the number of Peter's fails would return:

```
column: 2
row: 2
```

The `data` variable defined in your setup is also available here, allowing you to get the name of the person:

```
var name = data.getValue(selection.row, 0);
```

Or you could just run some ajax to get the contents of the appropriate text file.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am testing all of this on a webserver hosted on my own machine but I am unsure how other machines will be able to retrieve the content of a text file stored locally on the webserver?

Comment: As long as your script has permissions to read the file(s) you should be OK. Any chance of popping the data into a database?